# How to Call soap service in my AutocomleteTextview

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

how to call soap service in  AutocomleteTextview
i want to used in  AutocomleteTextview when user search by text or number...

Comment: I would suggest to have a look at the righthand side of this page, in the "Related" column. You've given way to little information for us to help you out. It's great that we know what you want. Now show us what effort you've put in to solve the problem and what hurdles are blocking you from getting there.

Comment: show what you have tried so far...

Comment: I used like this in spinner so i want this in auto compelte textview..............

Answer (score 0):

I used like this in spinner so i want this in auto complete

```
textviewSoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

        response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        System.out.println("string"+response.getProperty(0).toString());

        int count=Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty(0).toString());
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=0;i<=count;i++)
        {

            list.add(response.getProperty(i+1).toString());

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spleave.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


        }





        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.getProperty(0).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```